# Tags display order in Stack Exchange app - can it be made down first?

Tags: feature-request, tags, android-app

On the web, in the user profile tags (and badges too) are displayed in columns based on the sorting order:

[image]

But in the app they are displayed in rows:

[image]

My request is: can the app be made the same as the web currently is?

App version is 1.0.3.

Comment: I'd say that it makes more sense to display it from left to right in an app where the entire list might not fit on the screen (causing one to use the vertical scrollbar).

Comment: @devnull It shows only 10 top tags anyway and there's no scrolling or anything. Besides, scrolling sections of the screen horizontally is also used in apps (even in Stack Exchange app too).

Comment: [copy of bounty notice]: This is still the behavior of the app, and it is still odd to see the same list of 10 tags rearranged differently in the app, for no apparent reason. [no pun intended]